# Parsing through excel file and storing variables

Tags: javascript

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xlsx/0.8.0/jszip.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xlsx/0.8.0/xlsx.js"></script>
<script>
  var ExcelToJSON = function() {

    this.parseExcel = function(file) {
      var reader = new FileReader();

      reader.onload = function(e) {
        var data = e.target.result;
        var workbook = XLSX.read(data, {
          type: 'binary'
        });
        workbook.SheetNames.forEach(function(sheetName) {
          // Here is your object
          var XL_row_object = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_row_object_array(workbook.Sheets[sheetName]);
          var json_object = JSON.stringify(XL_row_object);
          console.log(JSON.parse(json_object));
          jQuery('#xlx_json').val(json_object);
        })
      };

      reader.onerror = function(ex) {
        console.log(ex);
      };

      reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
    };
  };

  function handleFileSelect(evt) {

    var files = evt.target.files; // FileList object
    var xl2json = new ExcelToJSON();
    xl2json.parseExcel(files[0]);
  }
</script>

<form enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input id="upload" type=file name="files[]">
</form>

<textarea class="form-control" rows=35 cols=120 id="xlx_json"></textarea>

<script>
  document.getElementById('upload').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
</script>
```

Hello, from the above snippet of code, I am trying to read in the variables from each parsed row in the excel file (the code takes an excel file and prints all the data by row), the best way to describe what I want would probably be something like this in c++(only way I know how to communicate).

```
   void read(string fileName) {
       // assume int a,b,c are already declared
       // assuming first row of parsed data is vector
       for (int i = 0; i < rows.size(); i++) {
            a = vector[i][0];
            b = vector[i][1];
            c = vector[i][2];
           // code for thing I am doing here(doesnt matter)
        }
 }
```

Is there something like this in javascript or a different method potentially?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that I figured out the answer to my question.

```
// to access a specific element, I need to do something like this
var obj = JSON.parse(json_object);
a = obj[0]["value"];
```